# What are the pros and cons of using a template engine like Jade?

Tags: html, node.js, template-engine, pug

I'm looking into developing a web app with Node.js. I'm coming from a PHP background where I didn't use a template engine (besides PHP itself) and I have always just written straight HTML. So, why should I or should I not use Jade or some other template engine?

Comment: You have used a templating language, PHP is one.

Comment: Right, which is why I said "besides PHP itself."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pros:

- Encourages good code organization (data generation is separate from presentation code)
- Output generation is more expressive (template syntax doesn't require a sea of string concatenation)
- Better productivity (common problems such as output encoding, iterating, conditionals, etc. have been handled)
- Generally requires less code overall (jade in particular has a very terse syntax)

Cons:

- Some performance overhead
- Yet another thing to learn

Comment: What is this "performance overhead". Are you suggesting you can dynamically generate HTML thats faster then a templating engine?

Comment: Absolutely.  It will always be faster to do something like `res.write('<h1>' + pageTitle + '</h1>');`, vs. `res.render('title-template', { title: pageTitle });` (in Express).  In most all cases the performance overhead is negligible, though. If jade (or other templating engine) is your bottleneck, you're doing pretty darn good everywhere else.

Comment: that's only true for patentic templates. Any serious template will be faster with a templating engine due to caching.

Comment: OK then. Templating engine  + caching is faster than writing directly to the response stream w/out Caching (sometimes :).  The same caching logic can (and should) be applied w/out a templating engine though.  Bottom line is that templating engines are an abstraction, and no matter what form they compile down to, carry some overhead. At the end of the day they're just writing to the response stream as well, so skipping the templating engine can only be faster, if done intelligently.

Comment: On a related note, in case it wasn't obvious from my previous comments, I do recommend the use of a templating engine.  The minimal performance overhead is a small price to pay for what you get in return.

Comment: I'm just stating that you can't do string concatonation that is faster, more intelligent and more maintainable without using a templating engine ;)

Comment: I'll agree on intelligent and maintainable :p. If the one and only criteria was speed, however, I'd personally forgo the templating engine.

Comment: I'm currently having serious bottleneck issues from Jade. I've been testing each piece of my templates to see if it's something I did and I can't find anything other than the more complex the template gets the slower it renders. It could be a memory leak or bug with Jade. I tried sending the same size content but with very basic markup and it flew. It's only when I have lots of nested elements.

Comment: @Mike It might be worth posting a question on that with your code and a description of your data. Despite my earlier comments about it being *technically* faster to generate the output yourself, I've never had a single occurrence where Jade itself became a bottleneck (and I've been using it extensively for awhile now).

Comment: I found out the issue was with the engine used by Jade when not running in production mode. Once I set NODE_ENV=production it flew.

Answer (score 1):

About JADE or any other template language that differ a lot from HTML:

First of all it is more time consuming to debug the produced HTML. You see HTML in the browser and you need to parse it back to JADE (in your brain) to compare with your editor content. This is very inconvenient and makes debugging harder then it should be.

Of course it may not be a problem if you are the only programmer who works on the code. It may seem so easy to match the html lines with JADE lines if you are the one who wrote them.

It is a problem when working in teams.